# Theoretically output Graham's number

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Graham's number \$G\$ is defined in this way:

\begin{align*}
u(3,n,1) & = 3^n \\
u(3,1,m) & = 3 \\
u(3,n,m) & = u(3,u(3,n-1,m),m-1)
\end{align*}

Then,

\begin{align*}
g_1 & = u(3,3,4) \\
g_2 & = u(3,3,g_1) \\
g_3 & = u(3,3,g_2) \\
& \vdots \\
G & = u(3,3,g_{63})
\end{align*}

You are given that \$u(3,3,2)=7625597484987\$ to check your code.

Your task is to write a program/function that will output the value of \$G\$ deterministically, given enough integer size and enough time.

## References

- [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number)
- [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)
- [Conway chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation)

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=83873,OVERRIDE_USER=48934;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20711/theoretical-algorithm-to-compute-grahams-number).

Comment: Is randomness allowed? If I just output random values, eventually Graham's number must be produced.

Comment: @miles Why on earth isn't it already a standard loophole? Clarified.

Comment: Are there any small intermediate values for `u` you could give us so we can check our code?

Comment: @xnor Added in.

Comment: [I've added it as a loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9447/45941)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79620/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor How is not known to terminate?

Comment: It's not that. The form of the recursive function is very similar.

Comment: Warning: u(3, 3, 2) = u(3, 2, 3) = 7625597484987, so you’ll also want to test on other values such as u(3, 5, 1) = 243 to make sure you got the argument order right.

Comment: @miles No, that's not true. Even with infinite trials there's no guarantee that you will ever generate a specific number because the numbers are infinite too.

Comment: @Bakuriu Solution: `i = 0; while True: print(i); i += 1`

Comment: @immibis He said generating numbers *at random*. Yours is a deterministic algorithm.

Comment: @Bakuriu `i = 0; while(true) {if(random() < 0.5) {print(i); print(i+1);} else {print(i+1); print(i);} i += 2;}`

Comment: @immibis That's still a fundamentally deterministic algorithm because you always choose either `i` or `i+1`. The point is, given random oracle that returns natural numbers completely at random, without using monotonic or "quasi-monotonic" sequences, even infinite numbers generated aren't enough to produce all natural numbers with certainty.

Comment: @Bakuriu I thought the point was to demonstrate a potential loophole?

Comment: @immibis Miles wanted to propose a solution like "n=get_random_number(); if n == graham; print n else: loop" saying that this program would fit the requirements. My point is that it does **not** fit the requirements, because even with infinite time there is no guarantee that it will ever output anything. Also, i don't really see why we should exclude this as a loop hole. Given that the program must output *only* the graham number you have to basically add some kind of check to avoid printing other invalid results, which fundamentally amounts to computing Graham number itself.

Comment: Does the base of the output matter? Obviously base-G wouldn't be allowed, but could e.g. base-256 be used?

Comment: @Mego Any base between 1 and 256 inclusive, would that be ok? Or should I extend to 1114112?

Comment: Up to you. Base-unicode could make for some interesting outputs. Unary would be terrifying.

Comment: [Graham's number?](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/07/21/03/3674EE4100000578-3700578-image-a-21_1469067327815.jpg)

Comment: You should have made the challenge to output Gn(m)

Comment: You can shorten your example by a lot as I have done [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120607/58880) by noting that when evaluating Graham's number, the number on the left is always 3.  Basically, make a two argument function that represents `3^^...^^x`.

Comment: @LeakyNun can you please put challenge rules in the post? Because it was not in the comments, I did not see the rule of a number base restriction.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer bro this challenge is 7 years old

Comment: @LeakyNun So???

Answer (score 50):

## [Binary lambda calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html), 114 bits = 14.25 bytes

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 4457 42b0 2d88 1f9d 740e 5ed0 39ce 80    DWB.-...t.^.9..
```

Binary:

```
010001000101011101000010101100000010110110001000000111111001110101110100000011100101111011010000001110011100111010
```

#### Explanation

```
01 00                                           (λx.
│    01 00                                        (λy.
│    │    01 01 01 110                              x
│    │    │  │  └─ 10                               y
│    │    │  └─ 00                                  (λm.
│    │    │       01 01 01 10                         m
│    │    │       │  │  └─ 00                         (λg.
│    │    │       │  │       00                         λn.
│    │    │       │  │         01 01 10                  n
│    │    │       │  │         │  └─ 110                 g
│    │    │       │  │         └─ 00                     (λz.
│    │    │       │  │              10                     z))
│    │    │       │  └─ 00                            (λn.
│    │    │       │       00                            λf.
│    │    │       │         01 111110                    x
│    │    │       │         └─ 01 110                    (n
│    │    │       │            └─ 10                      f))
│    │    │       └─ 1110                             x)
│    │    └─ 10                                     y)
│    └─ 00                                        (λf.
│         00                                        λz.
│           01 110                                   f
│           └─ 01 01 1110                            (x
│              │  └─ 110                              f
│              └─ 10                                  z)))
└─ 00                                           (λf.
     00                                           λz.
       01 110                                      f
       └─ 01 110                                   (f
          └─ 01 110                                 (f
             └─ 10                                   z)))
```

This is (λ*x*. (λ*y*. *x* *y* (λ*m*. *m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *n* *g* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. *x* (*n* *f*)) *x*) *y*) (λ*f*. λ*z*. *f* (*x* *f* *z*))) 3, where all numbers are represented as [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals).  Church numerals are the standard lambda calculus representation of natural numbers, and they are well suited to this problem because a Church number is defined by function iteration: *n* *g* is the *n*th iterate of the function *g*.

For example, if *g* is the function λ*n*. λ*f*. 3 (*n* *f*) that multiplies 3 by a Church numeral, then λ*n*. *n* *g* 1 is the function that takes 3 to the power of a Church numeral. Iterating this operation *m* times gives

*m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *n* *g* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. 3 (*n* *f*)) *n* = *u*(3, *n*, *m*).

(We use multiplication *u*(–, –, 0) rather than exponentiation *u*(–, –, 1) as the base case, because subtracting 1 from a Church numeral is [unpleasant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Derivation_of_predecessor_function).)

Substitute *n* = 3:

*m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *n* *g* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. 3 (*n* *f*)) 3 = *u*(3, 3, *m*).

Iterating that operation 64 times, starting at *m* = 4, gives

64 (λ*m*. *m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *n* *g* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. 3 (*n* *f*)) 3) 4 = *G*.

To optimize this expression, substitute 64 = 4^3 = 3 4:

3 4 (λ*m*. *m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *n* *g* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. 3 (*n* *f*)) 3) 4 = *G*.

Remember 4 = succ 3 = λ*f*. λ*z*. *f* (3 *f* *z*) as a lambda argument:

(λ*y*. 3 *y* (λ*m*. *m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *n* *g* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. 3 (*n* *f*)) 3) *y*) (λ*f*. λ*z*. *f* (3 *f* *z*)) = *G*.

Finally, remember 3 = λ*f*. λ*z*. *f* (*f* (*f* *z*)) as a lambda argument:

(λ*x*. (λ*y*. *x* *y* (λ*m*. *m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *n* *g* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. *x* (*n* *f*)) *x*) *y*) (λ*f*. λ*z*. *f* (*x* *f* *z*))) 3 = *G*.

Comment: Where could one find an interpreter for this language?

Comment: @Dennis https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html has a couple of them.

Comment: This is *awesome*. this deserves a sizeable bounty

Comment: `14.25 bytes` seems to be messing up the leaderboard. It is parsed as `25 bytes`, and you are therefore placed as second.

Comment: @Dan I fixed the leader board snippet, I think.

Comment: Neat, I did this in 120 bits [here](https://mindsarentmagic.org/2012/11/22/lambda-graham/), nice work shaving off 6 of them! BTW 120 bits is how many bits it takes to write "Graham's Number", assuming 8 bits per character and including the apostrophe and space.

Answer (score 41):

## Haskell, 41 bytes

```hs
i=((!!).).iterate
i(($3).i(`i`1)(*3))4 64
```

Explanation:

`` (`i`1)f n `` = `i f 1 n` computes the `n`th iterate of the function `f` starting at `1`.  In particular, `` (`i`1)(*3)n `` = 3^*n*, and iterating this construction *m* times gives `` i(`i`1)(*3)m n `` = *u*(3, *n*, *m*).  We can rewrite that as `` (($n).i(`i`1)(*3))m `` = *u*(3, *n*, *m*), and iterate this construction *k* times to get `` i(($3).i(`i`1)(*3))4 k `` = *g*_*k*.

Answer (score 17):

### Haskell, 43 bytes

```haskell
q=((!!).).iterate
g=q(`q`1)(3*)
q(`g`3)4$64
```

There has be a better way to flip `g` inline.

**46 bytes:**

```haskell
i=iterate
n%0=3*n
n%m=i(%(m-1))1!!n
i(3%)4!!64
```

---

**48 bytes:**

```haskell
n%1=3^n
1%m=3
n%m=(n-1)%m%(m-1)
iterate(3%)4!!64
```

Just writing down the definitions.

The base cases are a bit cleaner backed up to 0, though it saves no bytes. Perhaps it will make it easier to write an alternate definition.

```haskell
n%0=3*n
0%m=1
n%m=(n-1)%m%(m-1)
z=iterate(3%)2!!1
```

Comment: Can you use another function which has precedence lower than `+` so as to remove the parentheses between `m-1`?

Comment: I count 44 bytes, and what happened to 4 and 64?

Comment: Oops, I copied in my smaller-parameter test. I don't think I can change the operator precedence because I'm defining a new function and those have a default precedence. I can't overwrite an existing function.

Comment: I mean, I count 44 bytes after you change it back to 64.

Comment: I think you mean ``(`g`3)``, not ``(3`g`)``.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Oh yes. Your handling of that is much nicer. I've been searching for a shorter way to define `q` or its flip, but everything recursive is long and `foldr(.)` is messy.

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
M?H.UgbtH*G]3^3Gug3tG64 4
```

The first part `M?H.UgbtH*G]3^3G` defines a method `g(G,H) = u(3,G,H+1)`.

To test the first part, check that `7625597484987=u(3,3,2)=g(3,1)`: [`g3 1`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%3FH.UgbtH%2aG%5D3%5E3Gg3+1&debug=0).

The second part `ug3tG64 4` starts from `r0 = 4` and then compute `rn = u(3,3,r(n-1)) = g(3,r(n-1))` 64 times, outputting the final value (`r` is chosen instead of `g` to avoid confusion).

To test this part, start from `r0=2` and then compute `r1`: [`ug3tG1 2`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%3FH.UgbtH%2aG%5D3%5E3Gug3tG1+2&debug=0).

Comment: If g(G, H) = u(3, G, H + 1), you should have r(n) = u(3, 3, r(n − 1)) = g(3, r(n − 1) − 1), not g(3, r(n − 1)). I think your code is right but your explanation is missing the − 1.

Comment: You can save a byte by using unoffsetted u arguments (`^3` ↦ `*3`, `tG` ↦ `G`), and another byte with `.UgbtH*G]3` ↦ `e.ugNtHG1`.

Comment: An alternate way to save that second byte is `*G]3` ↦ `ShG`.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES7), 63 bytes

```
u=(n,m)=>n>1&m>1?u(u(n-1,m),m-1):3**n
g=n=>n?u(3,g(n-1)):4
g(64)
```

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Ugh, in that case I might as well revert that change.

Comment: This causes a stack overflow, might need to recheck your reccursion pattern.

Comment: This isn't simple ES7. This is unbounded ES7 (an imaginary variant of ES7 but with bignum, able to oracle infinitely, and is using decimal with /#xE^ as shorthand).

Answer (score 7):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 30 bytes

```
0000000: 286997 2449f0 6f5d10 07f83a 06fffa f941bb ee1f33  (i.$I.o]...:....A...3
0000015: 065333 07dd3e 769c7b                              .S3..>v.{
```

#### Disassembled

```
set numout
add 4
rwd 2
add 64
jmp
    sub 1
    fwd 3
    add 3
    rwd 1
    add 1
    jmp
        sub 1
        jmp
            fwd 1
            jmp
                jmp
                    sub 1
                    fwd 1
                    add 1
                    rwd 1
                jnz
                rwd 1
                jmp
                    sub 1
                    fwd 3
                    add 1
                    rwd 3
                jnz
                fwd 3
                jmp
                    sub 1
                    rwd 2
                    add 1
                    rwd 1
                    add 1
                    fwd 3
                jnz
                rwd 1
                sub 1
            jnz
            rwd 1
            jmp
                sub 1
            jnz
            add 1
            rwd 1
            sub 1
        jnz
        fwd 1
        jmp
            sub 1
            rwd 1
            add 3
            fwd 1
        jnz
        rwd 2
    jnz
    rwd 1
jnz
fwd 2
put
```

Or in Brainfuck notation:

```
++++<<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[->>>+++<+[-[>[[->+<]<[->>>+<<<]>>>[-<<+<+>>>]<-]<[-]+<-]>[-<+++>]<<]<]>>.
```

#### Testing

To compute *u*(3, *n*, *u*(3, *n*, … *u*(3, *n*, *m*) … )) with *k* nested calls to *u*, replace the first three `add` instructions `add 4`, `add 64`, `add 3` with `add m`, `add k`, `add n`, respectively.  Because Sesos can’t build numbers faster than in linear time, you’re practically limited to small values like *u*(3, 2, 2) = 27, *u*(3, 5, 1) = 243, and *u*(3, 1, *u*(3, 1, … *u*(3, 1, *m*) … )) = 3.

Comment: You can replace `[-]` with `,` since EOF is `0`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 57 bytes

```
4:64:1iw
:3{[1:N],3:N^.|t1,3.|hM:1-X,?t:1-:Mr:2&:Xr:2&.}.
```

Expects no Input nor Output and writes the result to `STDOUT`. This will produce a stack overflow at one point.

To check that this works for small values (e.g `u(3,3,2)`) you can replace the `4` with the value of `m` and `64` with `1`.

#### Explanation

This is basically a straightforward implementation of the explained way of computing the number.

- Main predicate:

  ```
  4:64:1i                    Call Predicate 1 64 times with 4 as initial input (the second
                             call takes the output of the first as input, etc. 64 times).
         w                   Write the final output to STDOUT
  ```
- Predicate 1:

  ```
  :3{...}.                   Call predicate 2 with input [Input, 3]. Its output is the 
                             output of predicate 1.
  ```
- Predicate 2:

  ```
  [1:N],                     M = 1
        3:N^.                Output = 3^N
  |                          Or
  t1,                        N = 1
     3.                      Output = 3
  |                          Or
  hM:1-X,                    X is M - 1
         ?t:1-:Mr:2&         Unify an implicit variable with u(3,N-1,M)
                    :Xr:2&.  Unify Output with u(3,u(3,N-1,M),X)
  ```

Answer (score 6):

## [Caramel](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/caramel), 38 bytes

```
(64 ((f->(f,1)),(n f->(3 (n f))),3) 4)
```

This is syntactic sugar for the lambda calculus expression 64 (λ*m*. *m* (λ*f*. λ*n*. *n* *f* 1) (λ*n*. λ*f*. 3 (*n* *f*)) 3) 4, where all numbers are represented as [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals).

Comment: `(n f->3 (n f))` shouldn't it read `n-1`?

Comment: @LeakyNun No. `(n f->3 (n f))` is a function for multiplication by three in [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals).

Comment: This challenge seems excessively simple in lambda calculus. Why?

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
n_ ±1:=3^n
1 ±m_:=3
n_ ±m_:=((n-1)±m)±(m-1)
Nest[3±#&,4,64]
```

Uses an undefined infix operator `±` which requires only 1 byte when encoded in ISO 8859-1. See @Martin's [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82740/6710) for more info. Mathematica functions support pattern matching for their arguments, such that the two base cases can be defined separately.

Comment: Since when did Mathematica use ISO 8859-1?

Comment: `n_ ±m_:=Nest[#±(m-1)&,3,n]`

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog (SWIPL), 129 / 137 bytes

```
g(1,R):-u(3,4,R).
g(L,R):-M is L-1,g(M,P),u(3,P,R).
u(N,1,R):-R is 3**N.
u(1,_,3).
u(N,M,R):-K is N-1,L is M-1,u(K,M,Y),u(Y,L,R).
```

To output Graham's number, query for `g(64,G).` (if the 8 bytes of this query are to be counted, the length is 137 bytes):

```
?- g(64, G).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

But as can be expected, this runs out of stack.

### Test

```
?- u(3, 2, X).
X = 7625597484987
```

Backtracking causes it to run out of stack:

```
?- u(3, 2, X).
X = 7625597484987 ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

### Ungolfed

The ungolfed version adds the general up-arrow notation, not just for 3, and uses cuts and checks to avoid backtracking and undefined situations.

```
% up-arrow notation
u(X, 1, _M, X) :- !.
u(X, N, 1, R) :-
    R is X**N, !.
u(X, N, M, R) :-
    N > 1,
    M > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    M1 is M - 1,
    u(X, N1, M, R1),
    u(X, R1, M1, R).

% graham's number
g(1,R) :- u(3, 3, 4, R), !.
g(L,R) :-
    L > 1,
    L1 is L - 1,
    g(L1,G1),
    u(3, G1, R).
```

Comment: How did you manage to do it without having the number `64` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @LeakyNun I edited to clarify; better?

Comment: Well, then add it into your code as well as your byte-count.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 161 bytes

```
u(int a, int b){if(a==1)return 3;if(b==1)return pow(3,a);return u(u(a-1,b),b-1);}
g(int a){if(a==1)return u(3,4);return u(3,g(a-1));}
main(){printf("%d",g(64));}
```

EDIT: saved 11 bytes by removing tabs and newlines.
EDIT: thx auhmann saved another byte and fixed my program

Comment: You could remove `g(int a){if(a==1)return u(3,4);return g(a-1);}` since it's not being used at all... Or are you forgetting something?

Comment: @auhmaan oops sorry, I used that number for testing and forgot to change it back. Thanks!!

Comment: Your `return g(a-1)` should be `return u(3,g(a-1))`.

Comment: I don't know if I should make a proper answer or just comment on this, but you can get this solution down to 114 bytes quite easily by realizing: Newlines between functions can be omitted. Omitting types for all argumens default them to int (think K&R). If statements like these can be written with nested ternary ops.

Code: `u(a,b){return a<2?3:b<2?pow(3,a):u(u(a-1,b),b-1);}g(a){return a<2?u(3,4):u(3,g(a-1));}main(){printf("%d",g(64));}`

Comment: @algmyr wow amazing! you should go post your own answer XD.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>114</s> 109 bytes

Based on the answer by @thepiercingarrow ([link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83999/45611)) I golfed the answer down quite a bit. Most savings are due to the abuse of default typing of arguments when doing K&R style functions and replacement of if statements with ternary operators. Added optional newlines between functions for readability.

Improved to 109 thanks to @LeakyNun.

```
u(a,b){return a<2?3:b<2?pow(3,a):u(u(a-1,b),b-1);}
g(a){return u(3,a<2?4:g(a-1));}
main(){printf("%d",g(64));}
```

Comment: `g(a){return u(3,a<2?4:g(a-1));}`

Comment: @LeakyNun That's a really good one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 85 bytes

```py
v=lambda n,m:n*m and v(v(n-1,m)-1,m-1)or 3**-~n
g=lambda n=63:v(2,n and g(n-1)-1or 3)
```

The `v` function defines the same function as the one found in [Dennis's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83923/45941): `v(n,m) = u(3,n+1,m+1)`. The `g` function is a zero-indexed version of the traditional iteration: `g(0) = v(2,3), g(n) = v(2,g(n-1))`. Thus, `g(63)` is Graham's number. By setting the default value of the `n` parameter of the `g` function to `63`, the required output can be obtained by calling `g()` (with no parameters), thus meeting our requirements for a function submission which takes no input.

Verify the `v(2,1) = u(3,3,2)` and `v(4,0) = u(3,5,1)` test cases online: [Python 2](http://ideone.com/a5lkxi), [Python 3](http://ideone.com/1XQwsQ)

Comment: It's kinda hard to verify, but your function `g` seems off. Shouldn't `v(2,n-1)` be `g(n-1)` or something similar?

Comment: @Dennis Good catch. I'll fix that.

Comment: Actually the offset between `u` and `v` means it should be `g(n-1)-1`.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I should not do programming while sleepy. I have to re-learn this every few days.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg In the future, please do not edit other people's submissions, even if it is to fix a mistake in an improvement/bugfix that you suggested.

Comment: @Mego Very well, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

### Dyalog APL, 41 bytes

```
u←{1=⍺:3⋄1=⍵:3*⍺⋄(⍵∇⍨⍺-1)∇⍵-1}
3u 3u⍣64⊣4
```

Test case:

```
      3u 2
7625597484987
```

Comment: You should be able to convert `1=⍺:3⋄1=⍵:3*⍺` to just `1=⍵:3*⍺` (`3=3*1`)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 64 bytes

Borrowing from [Theoretical algorithm to compute Graham's number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20711/theoretical-algorithm-to-compute-grahams-number).

```
def f(a,b=3)b<2?3:a<1?3*b:f(a-1,f(a,b-1))end;a=4;64.times{a=f a};p a
```

Simply put, `f a = u(3,3,a)` and it applies this 64 times.

Comment: A good explanation on why and how this code works would be nice.

Comment: It is a straightforward application of the definition of Graham's number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
’ß’ß’}ð‘3*ða?
4’2çƊ64¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zD82FE7eENjxpmGGsd3pBoz2UCFDA6vPxYl5nJoYV41OmARJfrcx1ernR00sOdMx41rYn8z/XfWEfBVEfB8L8RkAAyAQ)

I believe this is close to identical to [Dennis' deleted Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83923/66833) but was developed independently and uses a language feature that wasn't available at the time of his answer.

The first line defines a function \$v(n, m) = u(3, n+1, m+1)\$ and the TIO footer demonstrates this for \$u(3, 3, 2)\$, \$u(3, 5, 1)\$ and \$u(3, 1, 5)\$.

With our defined \$v\$, we then have the recurrence relation

\begin{align*}
g_1 & = v(2, 3) \\
g_{i+1} & = v(2, g_i - 1) \\
G = g_{64} & = v(2, g_{63} - 1)
\end{align*}

A more standard approach, which defines \$w(n, m) = u(3, n, m)\$ and then uses

\begin{align*}
g_1 & = w(3, 4) \\
g_{i+1} & = w(3, g_i) \\
G = g_{64} & = w(3, g_{63})
\end{align*}

comes out at 23 bytes:

```
3*ð’ßṛß’}ð«Ị¥?
4 3ç$64¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Y6/CGRw0zD89/uHP24flAVu3hDYdWP9zddWipPZeJgvHh5SpmJocW4ld3eLnS0UkPd8541LQm8j/Xf2MdBVMdBcP/RkACyAQA)

### How they work

#### \$v(n, m)\$

```
’ß’ß’}ð‘3*ða? - Helper link, v(n, m). Takes n on left, m on right
            ? - If:
           a  -   n and m are both non-zero
      ð       - Then:
’             -   n-1
 ß            -   v(n-1, m)
  ’           -   v(n-1, m)-1
    ’}        -   m-1
   ß          -   v(v(n-1, m)-1, m)
          ð   - Else:
       ‘      -   n+1
        3*    -   3^(n+1)

4’2çƊ64¡ - Main link. No arguments
4        - Set the return value and left argument to 4
    Ɗ    - Last 3 links as a monad f(x):
 ’       -   x-1
  2ç     -   v(2, x-1)
     64¡ - Starting with x = 4, iterate f(x) 64 times
```

#### \$w(n, m)\$

```
3*ð’ßṛß’}ð«Ị¥? - Helper link, w(n, m). Takes n on left, m on right
            ¥? - If:
          «    -   min(n, m)
           Ị   -   is insignificant (abs(x) ≤ 1)
  ð            - Then:
3*             -   3^n
         ð     - Else:
   ’           -   n-1
     ṛ         -   m
    ß          -   w(n-1, m)
       ’}      -   m-1
      ß        -   w(w(n-1, m), m-1)

4 3ç$64¡ - Main link. No arguments
4        - Set the return value and left argument to 4
    $    - Last two links as a monad g(x):
  3ç     -  w(3, x)
     64¡ - Starting with x = 4, iterate g(x) 64 times
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 107 bytes

```
u=:4 :0
if.y=1 do.3^x
elseif.x=1 do.3
elseif.1 do.x:(y u~<:x)u<:y
end.
)
(g=:(3 u 4[[)`(3 u$:@<:)@.(1&<))64
```

I'm working on converting `u` to an agenda, but for now it'll do.

Comment: Something like `u=:3^[\`[:(3$:])/[#<:@]@.*@]` (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

## F#, <s>111</s> 108 bytes

#### Edit

This is using the function below to calulcate Graham's number

```
let rec u=function|b,1->int<|3I**b|1,c->3|b,c->u(u(b-1,c),c-1)
and g=function|1->u(3.,4.)|a->u(3.,g (a-1))
g 63
```

Here's my previous answer which, well, didnt:

Pretty straightforward. Just a definition of the `u` function.

```
let rec u=function|a,b,1->a**b|a,1.,c->a|a,b,c->u(a,u(a,b-1.,c),c-1)
```

Usage:

```
u(3.,3.,2)
val it : float = 7.625597485e+12
```

If I assumed 3 as the value for a, I could cut it to 60:

```
let rec u=function|b,1->3.**b|1.,c->3.|b,c->u(u(b-1.,c),c-1)
```

Usage:

```
u(3.,2)
val it : float = 7.625597485e+12
```

Comment: The challenge is to write Graham’s number, not `u`. You can of course include any intermediate functions you need, such as `u` with or without its first argument fixed at 3.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg edited that in. Thanks. My previous comment seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

### R, <s>154</s> <s>142</s> <s>128</s> <s>126</s> 118 bytes

```
u=function(n,b)return(if(n&!b)1 else if(n)u(n-1,u(n,b-1))else 3*b)
g=function(x)return(u(if(x-1)g(x-1)else 4,3))
g(64)
```

I used the Wikipedia definition of this recursive function because for some odd reason the suggested one did not work... or I just suck at R golfing.

UPD: shaved off 12+14=26 bytes thanks to a tip from [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun). The prior version used the bulky and less efficient

```
u=function(n,b)if(n==0)return(3*b)else if(n>0&b==0)return(1)else return(u(n-1,u(n,b-1)))
g=function(x)if(x==1)return(u(4,3))else return(u(g(x-1),3))
```

UPD: shaved off 2+6+2 more bytes (again, kudos to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)) owing to an ingenious replacement with “if(x)” instead of “if(x==0)” because x<0 is never fed into the function... right?

Comment: @LeakyNun Thank you, updated the answer with acknowledgement.

Comment: Just a sec... Today is my first day of code golfing, there is much to learn!

Comment: You are invited to join [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: More golfing, please see the improvement.

Comment: Ta-dam, done, changed the function `u` in the same key as your `g` and saved 6 more bytes—awesome!

Comment: `b==0` is really `!b`.

Comment: I might misunderstand something... OK, if NOT `b` and `n`, then the first OR is used, otherwise the second OR. This is clear. But `u=function(n,b)return(n&!b|if(n)u(n-1,u(n,b-1))else 3*b)` yields infinite nesting... Seems that a pair of braces/parens is needed, but where?

Comment: Never mind, I don't think it works.

Comment: `u=function(n,b)return(if(n&!b)1 else if(n)u(n-1,u(n,b-1))else 3*b)`

Comment: This is so strange... The long version yields `7.625597e+12` for the test case `u(2,3)`. The one you suggests throws `evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options`. Is it really OK that it does not pass the test case?

Comment: I was mistaken in my thoughts (it's 3AM here now).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 114 bytes

ignore the line breaks; they are for readability only.

```
function u($n,$m){return$m>1&$n>1?u(u($n-1,$m),$m-1):3**$n;}
function g($x){return u(3,$x>1?g($x-1):4);}
echo g(63);
```

It is possible to integrate the second case into the first one: for `n=1`, `3^n` equals `3`.
This will save a few bytes on - as far as I can see - all existing answers; saved two bytes on my

**previous version, 62+43+11=116 bytes**

```
function u($n,$m){return$m>1?$n>1?u(u($n-1,$m),$m-1):3:3**$n;}
```

PHP´s left associativity of the ternary requires parentheses ... or a specific order of tests.
This saved two bytes on the parenthesized expression.

---

There is probably an iterative approach, which *may* allow further golfing ...
but I can´t take the time for it now.

Comment: wish I knew Sesos or had the time to learn it and translate right now

Comment: @Leaky Nun: I broke it down to only loops and addition. Is there a way in Sesos to add the value of one cell to another?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg: You´re probably right ... I got blisters on my eyeballs from looking at that algorithm. Will look at it again soon.