# A knight's graph on an N-by-N board

Tags: code-golf, number, array, matrix, chess

In chess, a knight can only move to the positions marked with X relative to its current position, marked with ♞:

[image: where a knight can move]

---

A [Knight's Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_graph) is a graph that represents all legal moves of the knight chess piece on a chessboard. Each vertex of this graph represents a square of the chessboard, and each edge connects two squares that are a knight's move apart from each other.

The graph looks like this for a standard 8-by-8 board.

[image]

---

#### Challenge:

Given an integer **N**, where **3 ≤ N ≤ 8**, output an **N-by-N** matrix representing a board, where the number of possible moves from each position is shown. For **N = 8**, the output will be a matrix showing the values of each vertex in the graph above.

The output format is flexible. List of lists or even a flattened list etc. are accepted formats.

---

#### Complete set of test cases:

```
--- N = 3 ---
2 2 2
2 0 2
2 2 2
--- N = 4 ---
2 3 3 2
3 4 4 3
3 4 4 3
2 3 3 2
--- N = 5 ---
2 3 4 3 2
3 4 6 4 3
4 6 8 6 4
3 4 6 4 3
2 3 4 3 2
--- N = 6 ---
2 3 4 4 3 2
3 4 6 6 4 3
4 6 8 8 6 4
4 6 8 8 6 4
3 4 6 6 4 3
2 3 4 4 3 2
--- N = 7 ---
2 3 4 4 4 3 2
3 4 6 6 6 4 3
4 6 8 8 8 6 4
4 6 8 8 8 6 4
4 6 8 8 8 6 4
3 4 6 6 6 4 3
2 3 4 4 4 3 2
--- N = 8 ---
2 3 4 4 4 4 3 2
3 4 6 6 6 6 4 3
4 6 8 8 8 8 6 4
4 6 8 8 8 8 6 4
4 6 8 8 8 8 6 4
4 6 8 8 8 8 6 4
3 4 6 6 6 6 4 3
2 3 4 4 4 4 3 2
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution in each language wins. **Explanations are encouraged!**

Comment: [Related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83933/20260) to query the number of knight moves from a square on an 8*8 board.

Comment: Can the output be a flat list of n*n elements?

Comment: This is literally just edge-cases! :)

Answer (score 13):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
t&l[2K0]B2:&ZvZ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0QtJ9rI2yDWychKLaosSvv/f1MA)

*(-1 byte thanks to @Luis Mendo.)*

The main part of the code is creating a matrix \$ K \$ for convolution:

$$ \mathbf{K} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\end{pmatrix} $$

(Relative to the centre of the matrix, each 1 is a valid knight's move.)

`t&l` - Form a nxn matrix of all 1s (where n is the input). Let this be M.

`[2K0]` - Push an array containing [2, 4, 0] on stack

`B`  - Convert all to binary, padding with 0s as needed

```
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0
```

`2:&Zv` - Mirror that on both dimensions, without repeating the final row/column ("symmetric range indexing").
This gives us the required matrix K.

```
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
```

`Z+` - Perform 2D convolution of K over the earlier matrix M (`conv2(M, K, 'same')`),
summing up the 1s at legal knight move targets for each position

Result matrix is displayed implicitly.

Comment: you can encode the convolution matrix as `11043370BP5e` but that's not any shorter...

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

```python
lambda n:[sum(2==abs((i/n-k/n)*(i%n-k%n))for k in range(n*n))for i in range(n*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBCoMwFETXeoq/EX5ii9RuSiAnsS4i1Taoo0Sl9PRpgoW2qxnevJlf62NC6Tt99YMZm5shqGrZRi61Ns3CbAsc@wJCss1CyyBENznqyYKcwb1lyA@z/6z2EeILzwe6CJUmrl22YSVNHUOkSbTc9Pw5RymZncVKu1uFXUJxiPwkJOp0n/0b)

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

Returns a string.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>--k?[n>3?'-2344-6-6'[(h=k=>k*2<n?~k:k-n)(k%n)*h(k/n|0)]||8:k-4&&2]+g(k):2)(n*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxLDoJAEAX3nqIX6nQzGTBAjEEHbuAFxETCVwd7jBo3gFdH2LqqpF7l3bJP9sqf18dbsS3KsdIj6xhrbXSslElOHAeJUH4QhmqrtuKEzTwZxz9w8jWRUUxoVkxOg8bjfkPnvt9NOlyv/bOs0VDkE7LDNFb2iQwagj0wHDTsJkpJ0C0Acssv25Zua2sUxykSIKdKgogE7f@CCpnce/bOGyw/WYsXD9O0oG7Z8TB49YXIvdkro0hZ0PwxczGMPw)

### How?

#### Special case: \$n=3\$

We fill each cell with \$2\$, except the center one which is set to \$0\$:

$$\pmatrix{2 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 0 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 2}$$

#### Other cases: \$3<n\le 8\$

For each cell \$(x,y)\$ with \$0\le x<n\$ and \$0\le y<n\$, we compute a lookup index \$i_{x,y}\$ defined as:

$$i_{x,y}=\min(x+1,n-x)\times \min(y+1,n-y)$$

For \$n=8\$, this gives:

$$\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 12 & 9 & 6 & 3\\
4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 16 & 12 & 8 & 4\\
4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 16 & 12 & 8 & 4\\
3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 12 & 9 & 6 & 3\\
2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1}$$

The lookup table \$T\$ is defined as:

$$T = [0,2,3,4,4,0,6,0,6]$$

where \$0\$ represents an unused slot.

We set each cell \$(x,y)\$ to:

$$\begin{cases}T(i_{x,y})&\text{if }i_{x,y} \le 8\\8&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 107 bytes

A naive implementation which actually tries all moves.

```javascript
n=>[...10**n-1+''].map((_,y,a)=>a.map((k,x)=>~[...b=i='01344310'].map(v=>k-=!a[x-v+2]|!a[y-b[i++&7]+2])+k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1LbsJAEET3nKKzoadpz8iOkUBA@wi5gGNFA8GRMfQgE1mgfK7ujBNWWdVHr1QH3/vLrmvO71bD636oZVApSudcls5majNGrNzJn415SW6JJyn8X2yTawzfI7qVRjDN8vk8z9I73kvRWnnw5dX2/Fh9Rnez27Jhni6qWBC3REMdOqMgkK9BYSOwjMpM8DEB2AW9hOPeHcObwacIIXCkGHCFtP4H1Ebp97cDKaBzh9CoQUCiu31WpHE76uRr@AE)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>23 22 14</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
²ḶdðạP€ċ2)
```

A monadic link yielding a flat list - uses the idea first used by KSab in [their Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170489/53748) - knight's moves have "sides" 1 and 2, the only factors of 2.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//wrLhuLZkw7DhuqFQ4oKsxIsyKf/Dh3PigbhH//84)** (footer calls the program's only Link and then formats the result as a grid)

Alternatively, also for 10 bytes, `²Ḷdðạ²§ċ5)` (knight's moves are all of the possible moves with distance \$\sqrt{5}\$)

#### How?

```
²ḶdðạP€ċ2) - Link: integer, n (any non-negative) e.g. 8
²          - square n                                 64
 Ḷ         - lowered range                            [0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,    10,   11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34,   35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,   43,   44,   45,   46,   47,   48,   49,   50,   51,   52,   53,   54,   55,   56,   57,   58,   59,   60,   61,   62,   63]
  d        - divmod (vectorises) i.e. x->[x//n,x%n]   [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[0,7],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[2,7],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],[4,0],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[5,0],[5,1],[5,2],[5,3],[5,4],[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[6,0],[6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],[6,6],[6,7],[7,0],[7,1],[7,2],[7,3],[7,4],[7,5],[7,6],[7,7]]
   ð     ) - new dyadic chain for each - call that L ( & e.g. R = [1,2] representing the "2nd row, 3rd column" ...-^ )
    ạ      -   absolute difference (vectorises)       [[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[0,2],[0,1],[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[3,2],[3,1],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[4,2],[4,1],[4,0],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4],[4,5],[5,2],[5,1],[5,0],[5,1],[5,2],[5,3],[5,4],[5,5],[6,2],[6,1],[6,0],[6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5]]
     P€    -   product of €ach                        [2,    1,    0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    2,    1,    0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    4,    2,    0,    2,    4,    6,    8,    10,   6,    3,    0,    3,    6,    9,    12,   15,   8,    4,    0,    4,    8,    12,   16,   20,   10,   5,    0,    5,    10,   15,   20,   25,   12,   6,    0,    6,    12,   18,   24,   30]
       ċ2  -   count 2s                          6:    ^-...1                  ^-...2                                                                  ^-...3                  ^-...4                        ^-...5      ^-...6
           - )                                                                                                     v-...that goes here
           -   ->                                  -> [2,    3,    4,    4,    4,    4,    3,    2,    3,    4,    6,    6,    6,    6,    4,    3,    4,    6,    8,    8,    8,    8,    6,    4,    4,    6,    8,    8,    8,    8,    6,    4,    4,    6,    8,    8,    8,    8,    6,    4,    4,    6,    8,    8,    8,    8,    6,    4,    3,    4,    6,    6,    6,    6,    4,    3,    2,    3,    4,    4,    4,    4,    3,    2]
```

---

**Previous 22 byter**

```
2RżN$Œp;U$+,ḟ€³R¤Ẉ¬Sðþ
```

A full program (due to `³`).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//MlLFvE4kxZJwO1UkKyzhuJ/igqzCs1LCpOG6iMKsU8Oww77/w4dH//84)** (footer calls the program's only Link and then formats the result as a grid)

Finds all moves and counts those which land on the board <s>probably</s> *definitely* beatable by calculating (maybe beatable by changing the "land on the board" logic).

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
+/+/2=×/¨|∘.-⍨⍳2⍴⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/5r62vrG9kenq5/aEXNo44ZerqPelc86t1s9Kh3C1Dlf6Ca/2lcxlxpXCZAbArEZkBsDsQWAA)

`⎕` evaluated input N

`2⍴⎕` two copies of N

`⍳2⍴⎕` the indices of an N×N matrix - a matrix of length-2 vectors

`∘.-⍨` subtract each pair of indices from each other pair, get an N×N×N×N array

`|` absolute value

`×/¨` product each

`2=` where are the 2s? return a boolean (0/1) matrix

Note that a knight moves ±1 on one axis and ±2 on the other, so the absolute value of the product of those steps is 2. As 2 can't be factored in any other way, this is valid only for knight moves.

`+/+/` sum along the last dimension, twice

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <strike>65</strike> <strike>40</strike> 33 bytes

This breaks down for N bigger then 9. So I'm happy N can be only go to 8 =)

```
⟦₅⟨∋≡∋⟩ᶠ;?z{{hQ&t⟦₅↰₁;Qz-ᵐ×ȧ2}ᶜ}ᵐ
```

- -25 bytes by switching to KSab's formula
- -7  bytes by flattening the array thanks to sundar

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@aWh/NX/Goo/tR50IQOX/lw20LrO2rqqszAtVKoAraNjxqarQOrNJ9uHXC4eknlhvVPtw2pxbI@f/f9H8UAA)

---

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <strike>44</strike> 36 bytes

This one also works for number higher then 9

```
gP&⟦₅⟨∋≡∋⟩ᶠ;z{{hQ&t⟦₅↰₁;Qz-ᵐ×ȧ2}ᶜ}ᵐ
```

- -8  bytes by flattening the array thanks to sundar

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/Pz1A7dH8ZY@aWh/NX/Goo/tR50IQOX/lw20LrAOqqqszAtVKoAraNjxqarQOrNJ9uHXC4eknlhvVPtw2pxbI@f/f0PR/FAA)

Comment: You can use the `⟨∋≡∋⟩` early on to generate the matrix coordinates too, and save 7 bytes overall (output is a flat list, which is allowed by OP): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@aWh/NX/Goo/tR50IQOX/lw20LrO2rqqszAtVKoAraNjxqarQOrNJ9uHXC4eknlhvVPtw2pxbI@f/f9H8UAA "Brachylog – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad), <s>51</s> <s>46</s> 39 bytes

```
{+/(⍵∘+¨(⊖,⊢)(⊢,-)(⍳2)(1¯2))∊,W}¨¨W←⍳⍵⍵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pM@f@/Wltf41Hv1kcdM7QPrdB41DVN51HXIk0gY5GOLpDq3WykqWF4aL2Rpuajji6d8NpDKw6tCH/UNgEoA9LWu/X///8WAA)

### How?

Counts the number of valid knight moves for each square by seeing which knight moves would land on the board:

```
{+/(⍵∘+¨(⊖,⊢)(⊢,-)(⍳2)(1¯2))∊,W}¨¨W←⍳⍵⍵
 +/                                     - The number of ...
                            ∊,W         - ... in-bounds ...
        (⊖,⊢)(⊢,-)(⍳2)(1¯2)             - ... knight movements ...
   (⍵∘+¨                   )            - ... from ...
{                              }¨¨W←⍳⍵⍵ - ... each square
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>114</s> <s>103</s> 92 bytes

```python
lambda n:[sum((d*c>d)+(d*c>c)for d in(y%n,n-y%n-1)for c in(y/n,n-y/n-1))for y in range(n*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcgxDsIwEETRnlNsg7QbEkVARSS4CFAYG8NKZBKZUPj0JtkCmvmjN@bpOWBX4vFSXq6/BUfozu9PzxwqfwqysXqJQ6JACs5r1GjmbbaG3rA1bBc0zbNScnjcGRXkWhbUP@5rOki3IhqTYiL9vcgq5Qs)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 161 bytes

```
.+
*
L$`_
$=
(?<=(¶)_+¶_+)?(?=(?<=(¶)_*¶_*)__)?(?<=(¶)__+)?(?=(?<=(¶)_*)___)?_(?=(?<=___)_*(¶))?(?=__+(¶))?(?=(?<=__)_*¶_*(¶))?(?=_+¶_+(¶))?
$.($1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY07DsIwEET7Occg@SNF2nwgBZZLGu6woaCgoUCcLQfIxRw7sUJBt/Pmafbz/L7eD0knc5tS4@Fw56RggInXYJbZql9m9TaaGA7kMnJWtdCK/pSMcq@VlaCuNJuW9ePe6zr6M7a3ewQbQ2HLjj0HnnnhaFMSoAU6oAcGYAREVg) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
L$`_
$=
```

List the value once for each `_` in the value, i.e. create a square.

```
(?<=(¶)_+¶_+)?
(?=(?<=(¶)_*¶_*)__)?
(?<=(¶)__+)?
(?=(?<=(¶)_*)___)?
_
(?=(?<=___)_*(¶))?
(?=__+(¶))?
(?=(?<=__)_*¶_*(¶))?
(?=_+¶_+(¶))?
```

Starting at the `_` in the middle of the regex, try to match enough context to determine whether each of the eight knight's moves is possible. Each pattern captures a single character if the match succeeds. I tried using named groups so that the number of captures directly equals the desired result but that cost 15 bytes.

```
$.($1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8)
```

Concatenate all the successful captures and take the length.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 34 bytes

Yet another Mathematica built-in.

```
VertexDegree@KnightTourGraph[#,#]&
```

Returns a flattened list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8stagktcIlNb0oNdXBOy8zPaMkJL@0yL0osSAjWllHOVbtv0t@dEBRZl5JdJ6Crp1CWnRebKyOQnWejoKxjoJFbex/AA)

Comment: I actually made a comment under the challenge with this answer (although not correct syntax since I don't know WL). I removed it after a bit, since I figured someone else might want to post it as a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>133</strike> 125 bytes

This solution should work on any size board.

```c
#define T(x,y)(x<3?x:2)*(y<3?y:2)/2+
a,b;f(i){for(a=i--;a--;)for(b=i+1;b--;)printf("%i ",T(a,b)T(i-a,b)T(a,i-b)T(i-a,i-b)0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU7NCsIwDD7bpwgTIbUt6naRdcWX2NFLN53kYJXhYWPs2WuKDg8Gknxf8uWnNbe2jXF9uXYUrlDjoEeJQ1WchjKXWxwZjYx2uRJeN7ZDklP36NE7MsZ6dplo40gdbJPos6fw6jDbEGS6Rp6SNZL5ZK/JLDyhvbRzZD3cPQWUMAlg442AqUqusECVO3JUamkn@10p@QyQtGKVnrN/inPIvtVZzPEN)

Comment: @ceilingcat Of course, thanks! But I don't see what the second suggestion changes

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU7NCsIwDD7bpygTIbEt4naRdcWX2NFLNzfJwSrDw8bYs9cUHR4MJPm@5MtPa25tG@P22vUUOlnDqCdUMFbFeSxz3MPEaGJ0yIXXje2BcO4fA3hHxljPjok2jtTRNok@BwqvHrIdyUzXwFNYA5lP9prMyhNCu0SWy7unAChnIdl4oYRUJVdYSZU7cVRqbSf7HSn5iiS0YpN@s3@KS8i@1UUs8Q0 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")