# A list of number modulus their indices in the list

Tags: code-golf, math, number

**A simple one:**
Take a list of positive integers as input and output the numbers modulus their 1-based index in the list.

If the input integers are `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}` then the output should be `{a%1, b%2, c%3, d%4, e%5, f%6, g%7}` where `%` is the modulus operator.

---

**Test cases:**

```
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
 0  1  2  3  1  5  4  3  2  1

8 18  6 11 14  3 15 10  6 19 12  3  7  5  5 19 12 12 14  5
0  0  0  3  4  3  1  2  6  9  1  3  7  5  5  3 12 12 14  5

1
0

1  1
0  1
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

```hs
($[1..]).zipWith mod
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WQyXaUE8vVlOvKrMgPLMkQyE3P@V/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmkK0oYGOpY6FjrmOmY6pjomOsY6RjmHsfwA)

A trick to `flip` I learned from [a golf of Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83883/20260).

Answer (score 11):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 73 bytes

```
f={l=_this;r=[];i=0;while{i<count l}do{r=r+[(l select i)%(i+1)];i=i+1};r}
```

**Call with:**

```
numList = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
hint format["%1\n%2", numList, numList call f];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: What... this is a thing?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Yes. The game allows players to create their own scenarios, and there is an in-game scripting language designed to supplement mission designing. However, since the language is Turing-complete, you can do pretty much whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
i=1
for x in input():print x%i;i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcI7CoAwEAXA3lO8RlB8hRv/Sk4ituI2SZAI8fTRYcIbL@9MzmqlOP2NBHX/8MSqXsOtLiKVumljJeddWmIhZmIiRmIgeqIjDCHHBw)

Counts the index up manually, as per [a tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40791/20260).

Comment: If you can exit with an error (I forget if that's the default) you can shave a [couple bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWkKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69EITOvoLREQ1M10zpT29bw/39DAy5LLgsucy4zLlMuEy5jLiMuQwA).

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
%J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/V6////9GGBjoKCpZAbAHE5kBsBsSmQGwCxMZAbATEhrEA)

**Explanation:**

```
%J
 J List 1 .. len(input). This is results in a list of the indexes.
%  Modulo.
```

Basically, the code modulos the original list by the list of indexes.

Comment: As soon as I saw this question, I thought "that's `%J` in Jelly, I wonder if anyone has answered with that answer?". I guess someone else had the same idea :-D

Comment: @ais523 You think you were the only one? Think again!

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>4</s>, 3 bytes

```
tf\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcG5AYAgEACwVTKCgPLMohY2VNqx/5l8z3oj1rwizrQx6DQqBzuFTLp/)

*One byte saved thanks to @LuisMendo!*

Answer (score 6):

## R, 27 bytes

```r
x=scan();cat(x%%1:sum(1|x))
```

saved 5 bytes thanks to @Jarko

saved 4 more thanks to @Giuseppe

saved 2 more thanks to @Taylor Scott

Saved 2 more thanks to @returnbull

Comment: 35 it is - removed unneeded last paren

Comment: you don't need the `' '` (space) at the end of `cat`; that's the default separator

Comment: you can drop 2 bytes to get 33 by reducing this down to `x<-scan();cat(x%%1:length(x)," ")` -- oh and a couple formatting tips, 1) you only need 4 spaces to the left of your code for it to be properly indented and marked 2) you can add a `<!-- language-all: lang-r -->` flag before your code to have it be highlighted (though this changes little in this example) 3) you do not need the brakets around your language's name 4) oh and you don't need to make a comment when you make edits to a post

Comment: (1) You can use `=` instead of `<-` to save a byte.

(2) The specification says "output" rather than "print", so you can probably drop the `cat()`, saving 5 bytes.

(3) `sum(1|x)` is one byte shorter than `length(x)`.

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>24</s> 18 bytes

```
pryr::f(x%%seq(x))
```

Evaluates to the function:

```
function (x) 
x%%seq(x)
```

Which uses `seq_along()` to create a vector of the same length as `x`, starting at 1, and then `%%` to take the modulo.

Default behaviour of `seq` when presented with a vector is `seq(along.with = x)` which is the same output as `seq_along(x)`, but 6 bytes shorter.

Comment: `seq(x)` is a handy thing to have around, since I'm always using `1:length(x)`.

Comment: @Giuseppe Yeah I was kinda surprised as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ā%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SKPq///RFjqGFjpmOoaGOoYmOsY6hqY6hgYgvqWOoRGQb65jCoQQHgiZ6JjGAgA) or [Try all tests](https://tio.run/##LYvBDYAgEASr8TcPFzmBWggPTWzBhKe92Rceicl@ZjOz2nHqGnfv432WwahVK4VMYseIbATUqBllvyQ0TxkuOhcUnJPL9tNcxDyaoQetfQ)

```
ā  # Push the range(1, len(a) + 1)
 % # Mod each element in the input by the same one in this list
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought it'd be like `DgL%`, nice.

Comment: @carusocomputing I originally had `gL%` because I forgot about `ā`.

Comment: mind going a bit more in-depth on `ā` for me? I believe I've never used it is it just like `for each` but in a `1 to n+1` manner like `vy<code>})` but implied `vy<code>})`?

Comment: @carusocomputing it pushes an array with values 1 to the length of the popped array. It's equivalent to `gL`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SOP//9EWOoYWOmY6hoY6hiY6xjqGpjqGBiC@pY6hEZBvrmMKhBAeCJnomMYCAA)

Comment: Does it also dupe the input? Or is implicit input now extended automatically to the closest available input?

Comment: @carusocomputing Any time something is popped and the stack is empty it will use the next item from the input and keep returning the last item when it runs out of input.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⍳∘≢|⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHvZsfdcx41Lmo5lHXIqCQgqGBgoKlgoKFgoK5goKZgoKpgoKJgoKxgoKRgoIhVxpQwtACJGFoqGAIljA0BesBilgqGBqBlZqDtZlCRUAIqNIUqBlkAFAfAA)

`⍳` the indices

`∘` of

`≢` the length of the argument

`|` that modulus

`⊢` the argument

Comment: Always amazed that a "mainstream" language can be so economical. The APL way seems naturally to be code golf: e.g. `(~T∊T∘.×T)/T←1↓⍳R ⍝ primes up to R` or `life←{↑1 ω∨.∧3 4=+/,¯1 0 1∘.⊖¯1 0 1∘.⌽⊂ω} ⍝ Game of Life`

Comment: @YiminRong You can do better: Primes to R: `(⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳R` and GoL (in Version 16.0): `K∊⍨⊢∘⊂⌺3 3` where K is a constant.

Comment: @YiminRong Try the primes finder [here](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%u22A2%7E%u2218.%D7%u2368%291%u2193%u2373100&run)!

Answer (score 5):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 19 bytes

```
;ww.1I!@s%Ow;)Sow.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9@6vFzP0FPRoVjVv9xaMzi/XE/l/38LBUMLBQUzBUNDBUMTBQVjBUNTBUMDsIilgqERSETBXEHBFIQgIiAEVGkKAA)

```
    ; w
    w .
1 I ! @ s % O w
; ) S o w . $ .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch It Run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIDsgdwogICAgdyAuCjEgSSAhIEAgcyAlIE8gdwo7ICkgUyBvIHcgLiAkIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=OCAxOCAgNiAxMSAxNCAgMyAxNSAxMCAgNiAxOSAxMiAgMyAgNyAgNSAgNSAxOSAxMiAxMiAxNCAgNQ==&speed=10)

A fairly straight forward implementation.

- `1` push 1 to the stack to start the index
- `I!@` get the integer input and halt if 0
- `s%Ow` swap the index up, mod, output result and change lane
- `;)` remove result and increment index
- `Sow` push 32, output space and change lane (heading down from o)
- `$O` jump the output
- `w;w` change lange, remove 32 from stack and change lane onto the `I` input

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 22 bytes

```
#&@@@Mod~MapIndexed~#&
```

One more Mathematica approach.

Comment: `MapIndexed@Mod` is _almost_ good enough :'(

Answer (score 4):

## [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), <s>75</s> 70 bytes

```
      +`  , + +   *    +  + +      +*   +    *  .               + + .'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYpBEoAgDAPveUVuzoDDWAXF3@gX0IuvrxS8mOTQTXrdZymPKpv8QY701aRrBT@y2/WiTYF/2VcYVDMkY4UIJGKBJMhkvEPmyhtSdSdLRHoB)

#### Explanation

This is an infinite loop that keeps reading numbers from the input and increasing a counter initiallized at `1`. For each pair of input and counter, the modulus is computed and printed.

To end the loop when input has been exhausted, the following trick is used. When no more input is available, trying to read one more number gives a `0`. Thus, we divide the read number by itself, and if it is `0` the program ends with an error. Else we discard the result and continue.

```
      +              Push 1. This is the initial value of the counter
`                    Mark label
  ,                  Read number from input and push it. Gives 0 if no more input
 +                   Duplicate top of the stack
 +                   Duplicate top of the stack
   *                 Pop two numbers and push their division. Error if divisor is 0
    +                Pop (discard) top of the stack
  +                  Swap top two numbers
 +                   Duplicate top of the stack
      +              Push 1
*                    Pop two numbers and push their sum. This increases the counter
   +                 Rotate stack down, to move increased counter to bottom
    *                Pop two numbers and push their modulus
  .                  Pop a number and print it as a number
               +     Push 10
 +                   Duplicate top of the stack
 .                   Pop a number (10) and print it as ASCII character (newline)
'                    If top of the stack is non-zero (it is, namely 10) go to label
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
l⟦₁;?↔z%ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P@fR/GWPmhqt7R@1TalSfbh1wv//0YYGOpY6FjrmOmY6pjomOsY6RjqGsf@jAA)

#### Explanation

```
l⟦₁          [1, ..., length(Input)]
   ;?↔z      Zip the Input with that range
       %ᵐ    Map mod
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>5</s> <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
uVÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=dVbE&input=WzEwIDmgOKA3oDagNaA0oDOgMiAxXQ)

-1 byte thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

Comment: I think you can save a byte with `®%°T` (actually, you could still use `Y` there if you wanted)

Comment: Aha. Thanks, @ETHproductions.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 22 bytes

```
pryr::f(x%%1:sum(x|1))
```

R performs 1:length(x) before doing the modulus.

Comment: Nice find with `sum(x|1)`!

Comment: Just found out that using `seq()` instead of `seq_along()` does the same thing. So that is a few bytes shorter again.

Comment: I was going to tell you that, but I didn't have the rep to comment. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 5 bytes

`#äL¹%`

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=I-RMuSU=&in=KDEwICA5ICA4ICA3ICA2ICA1ICA0ICAzICAyICAxKQ==)

## Explanation

```
#     ; read the list from standard input
 äL   ; push its length
   ¹  ; converted to 1-based range
    % ; point-wise modulo
      ; implicitly output list
```

---

## Itr, [4 bytes](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=I0y5JQ==&in=KDEwICA5ICA4ICA3ICA2ICA1ICA0ICAzICAyICAxKQ==)

`#L¹%`

The `ä` before the `L` is no-longer necessary in newer versions

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda l:[v%(i+1) for i,v in enumerate(l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHLCoQgAAXQX7mbAWXuInsXzJdUCyMlwSzEgvl6O@f6p/0MZba/OXt9rJuGH6fnI9xXSdgzwvGBCzDhPkzUyQgvl3xFFxKsmFRBDERPdERLNERNVERJqEXmFw)

Comment: You can remove the space before the `for`

Comment: 41 bytes: `lambda l:[v%-~i for i,v in enumerate(l)]`

Comment: Or, `lambda l:[v%i for i,v in enumerate(l,1)]`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
#~Mod~Range@Length@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfuc43P6UuKDEvPdXBJzUvvSTDQVntf0BRZl6JQ5qCQ7WFjoIhEJsBKUMgNtFRMAZSpkBsABG1BGIjsKi5joIpGMHEwBiow7T2PwA)

or **20 bytes** (by Martin)

```
#~Mod~Range@Tr[1^#]&
```

Comment: `Tr[1^#]` for `Length@#`.

Comment: that one doesn't work on mathics, so I'm keeping them both

Comment: You are missing a `#` as the second last character in your first answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 22 bytes

```
zipWith(flip mod)[1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P822KrMgPLMkQyMtJ7NAITc/RTPaUE8v9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKaQrShgY6ljoWOuY6ZjqmOiY6xjpGOYex/AA)

Also: `flip(zipWith mod)[1..]`.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, <s>59</s> 46 Bytes

#### Golfed

Anonymous VBE Immediate window funtion that takes a space ( ) delimited array string as input from range `[A1]` and output the numbers modulus their 1-based index in the starting list to the VBE immediate window

```vba
For Each n In Split([A1]):i=i+1:?n Mod i;:Next
```

Input / Output:

```vba
[A1]="10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1" ''# or manually set the value
For Each n In Split([A1]):i=i+1:?n Mod i;:Next
 0  1  2  3  1  5  4  3  2  1
```

#### Old `Sub`routine version

Subroutine that takes input as a passed array and outouts to the VBE immediate window.

```vba
Sub m(n)
For Each a In n
i=i+1
Debug.?a Mod i;
Next
End Sub
```

Input / Ouput:

```vba
m Array(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
 0  1  2  3  1  5  4  3  2  1
```

#### Ungolfed

```vba
Option Private Module
Option Compare Binary
Option Explicit
Option Base 0 ''# apparently Option Base 1 does not work with ParamArrays

Public Sub modIndex(ParamArray n() As Variant)
    Dim index As Integer
    For index = LBound(n) To UBound(n)
        Debug.Print n(index) Mod (index + 1);
    Next index
End Sub
```

Input / Output:

```vba
Call modIndex(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
 0  1  2  3  1  5  4  3  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ż%
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?code=%C5%BC%25&input=%5B10%2C%209%2C%208%2C%207%2C%206%2C%205%2C%204%2C%203%2C%202%2C%201%5D&flags=)

##### Explanation

```python
ż%  # Implicit input
 $  # Vectorised modulo
ż   # List [1..length]
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 46 bytes

```
|v|v.iter().zip(1..).map(|(n,i)|n%i).collect()
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+solution%3A+fn%28%26%5Busize%5D%29+-%3E+Vec%3Cusize%3E+%3D+%7Cv%7C+v.iter%28%29.zip%281..%29.map%28%7C%28n%2C+i%29%7C+n+%25+i%29.collect%28%29%3B%0A++++%2F%2F+%7Cv%7Cv.iter%28%29.zip%281..%29.map%28%7C%28n%2Ci%29%7Cn%25i%29.collect%28%29%0A%0A++++assert_eq%21%28%0A++++++++solution%28%26%5B10%2C+9%2C+8%2C+7%2C+6%2C+5%2C+4%2C+3%2C+2%2C+1%5D%29%2C%0A++++++++vec%21%5B0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+1%2C+5%2C+4%2C+3%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A++++%29%3B%0A%0A++++assert_eq%21%28%0A++++++++solution%28%26%5B8%2C+18%2C+6%2C+11%2C+14%2C+3%2C+15%2C+10%2C+6%2C+19%2C+12%2C+3%2C+7%2C+5%2C+5%2C+19%2C+12%2C+12%2C+14%2C+5%5D%29%2C%0A++++++++vec%21%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+3%2C+4%2C+3%2C+1%2C+2%2C+6%2C+9%2C+1%2C+3%2C+7%2C+5%2C+5%2C+3%2C+12%2C+12%2C+14%2C+5%5D%2C%0A++++%29%3B%0A%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26%5B1%5D%29%2C+vec%21%5B0%5D%29%3B%0A%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26%5B1%2C+1%5D%29%2C+vec%21%5B0%2C+1%5D%29%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
{_,,:).%}
```

Anonymous block that expects an array on the stack and replaces it by the output array.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP0fbaFgaKGgYKZgaKhgaKKgYKxgaKpgaAAWsVQwNAKJKJgrKJiCEEQEhIAqTWP/V8fr6Fhp6qnW/q8r@A8A)

#### Explanation

```
{       }    e# Define block
 _           e# Duplicate
  ,          e# Length
   ,         e# Range, 0-based
    :)       e# Add 1 to each entry
      .%     e# Vectorized modulus
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 9 bytes

```
>:@i.@#|[
```

1 ... n | original list

`|` is mod

Answer (score 1):

## C, 52 bytes

```
i;f(n,l)int*l;{for(i=0;i++<n;)printf("%d ",*l++%i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvLCsIwFIThfZ9iKBSS5giNdzn2ScSFRCIH0ii1u5Bnj42z/JjfbV7OlSLsVaSgJS594OTfs5JxYDHmGll/5tW9arsnWuqDMZ1ozmVFTA@JSjepwboKQb7LzQ53jEh2IFwIZ8KJcCQcCHvCjrAl2Mz/xqv6qpXmJpcf)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

```
a=>a.map((x,y)=>x%++y)
```

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 13

```
{print $1%NR}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uqAoM69EQcVQ1S@o9v9/QwMuSy4LLnMuMy5TLhMuYy4jLkMA).

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 35

```
lmap l $L {puts [expr $l%[incr i]]}
```

### [demo](http://rextester.com/UVQG28963)

Answer (score 1):

## GNU APL 1.2, 9 bytes

```
(⍳⍴R)|R←⎕
```

APL operates from right to left, hence the parentheses.

`R←⎕` assigns user input to vector `R`.

`⍴R` gives the length of the vector; `⍳⍴R` gives a vector with all numbers from 1 to that length (so the indices).

`|` is the mod operator (`a|b` yields `b%a`). APL operates on arrays, so the code snippet a vector containing each element from the user's input mod its index.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 22 bytes

```
a->[a[n]%n|n<-[1..#a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBCsIwEER/ZakIDUyKWxubgPZHwh72UilICKUXwX@PiQh7mDezL@u@2WcuKz2oqF2ixiTn9El3G3kYTipSNOfXu1eyC@V9S0eNXYOO1l6NAcXIFwR4zLjBYcIVI1jq4MG@dszg1rIDh8YBPFae67f7U7upOT@xCiKmfAE)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5

```
.e%bh
```

[Online test](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.e%25bh&input=%5B10%2C%209%2C%208%2C%207%2C%206%2C%205%2C%204%2C%203%2C%202%2C%201%5D&debug=0).

```
    hk     # 1-based index of (implicit) lambda variable
   b       # element
  %        # element mod (1-based index)
.e    Q    # enumerated map over (implicit) input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(n)mod(n,1:nnz(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw9CsIwAIV3T/GNCZTgq41NBKH3KA6idjNdxKGXj0ksvOH9r4/P/fvKy9U5lyeT7Ht9mtTpktJWlM2LmXWECAFGOIOHAU7Qg272UCoBhZpJqGXy1FlxIupbe2xLvzsVQ5Xx/7AfqSsk/wA)

An anonymous function that takes **n** as input, and performs element-wise modulus with the list **1, 2, 3**.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 18 bytes

```
V1R&,{v.m1+v%}&,=;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/zDBITae6TC/XULtMtVZNx9b6////hgb/Lf9b/Df/b/bf9L/Jf@P/Rv8NAQ)

### Explanation

```
V1R&,{v.m1+v%}&,=;  Implicit input from commandline args
V1R                 Create stack2, push 1 to it, and return to stack1
   &,               Reverse stack1
     {.......}      Foreach loop, runs for each item in stack1
      v             Switch to stack2
       .m           Duplicate last item on stack and move duplicate to stack1
         1+         Increment last item on stack
           v%       Return to stack1, pop last 2 items and push modulus result
              &,    Reverse stack1
                =   Output stack1
                 ;  Suppress implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 / C#, 39 bytes

```
a->{for(int i=0;i<a.length;a[i]%=++i);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##rVFBboMwELznFXupBMrGitPQELlU6gOaS46Ig0uc1BQMMiZVhHg7XXAOvTfSWtoZzc547UJe5apulClO36Oumto6KIhjndMle7dW3lqxyEvZtvAhtekXANo4Zc8yV3CYIMC11ifIA@LTTIaCuIEOVeuk0zkcwEACo1y99efaTjrQyVroV8lKZS7uS8hUZ0/JcqlDMYzCDzfdZ0nDd485o6IbBEdntbmkGcjQx8@5NjHqx7c9X@MeY9zhC0a4xWfcIB/ErDUsD2zo@@OtdapidedYQ5auNIFfmLnah5CUtLP4r3@MPCZvzpFP7jxCSiS8R74hvKPU6I6m2mL0yPSHrsL/9TLTRw/jLw)

Also works in C# by replacing `->` with `=>` and `length` with `Length`:

```
a=>{for(int i=0;i<a.Length;a[i]%=++i);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##tZCxasMwEIZ3P8VhKFjkaqw0ThwUBUq3kkwdOhgPQlXTg1QCSbQU42d3ZTdDHqABDfoP3X3fSYd77bwZ9VmFAMc@AwhRRdLw5egNjopswaYqwMtPiOazfNSRnN2RjW23Bw0SRiX3/bvzRaoByUrQTpUHY0/xQ6iWuju5WBATwzhNEdk8bG730prvv2vPK9xigxtcY40rfMAl8kHMb3XhmbhWeHI2uLMpXz1FcyBrirztq6HLMcl7sqfy2SXvHHP0jF2I17AGeZNAnCOfULzGhE95i3yZ8iYp1Jc0nRXWN1O53ZL8/z4QYMiG8Rc)

**Explanation:**

```
a->{                       // Method with integer-array parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;i<a.length;  //  Loop over the indexes of the array (0-indexed)
      a[i]%=++i            //   And replace every integer with itself mod (1+i)
  );                       //  End of loop
}                          // End of method
```

Modifies the input-array, hence the lack of a return.

Comment: Essentially what I'd do in C# +1, could also comment about it working for C# too if you change `->` to `=>` and capitalise`length`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->x{x.map{|y|$.+=1;y%$.}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9euorpCLzexoLqmskZFT9vW0LpSVUWvtvZ/gUKanka0oYGOpY6FjrmOmY6pjomOsY6RjmGs5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4, 18 bytes

```
zip(a,1...).map(%)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 57 bytes

```
(defun m(l &aux(i 0))(mapcar(lambda(x)(mod x(incf i)))l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RCoJAEEV/5RBUM2@tZdnnbG6CsOtKGQiRv26j9BDMw3DmHubWsX328yzh3rw6kkR2/jVKy0FVku9r/5Do0y14GQ3kgB27uqFV1ag6S8y5p8kPRtqOvYg7wBUquMAZSjjBEQpwKhWuWrhzuJW7kkUxcsUVa/KyWuWPLGPJUsV0s1QJGbGfyQ8MbKb3VASmz7T927YbaySJ0YrOXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 7 bytes

```perl6
*Z%1..*
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##VY4xT8MwFIR3/4pbQE7auHVD0lRRISs7E2IpzqNEShMrcREV4pex8Z@Yg@2kUis9Wfa9@86nqavT4dgTPlKhcnY44Va1JWE7hM83Uohw8GJhqDfYoq4a6nkg9h1p/hAGvz9CtYdXvngpZwv3emyM6FrTdnwV5MwFP1kyZ7reNZj5mJy9td2UGN2Do6gafTRzFPSpSRkqEeCLAVUflUS6PsFV4qMtuPDNJ1Tsq96w70EugQ2QAWsgBRLgDoiBFSAZ7Fb6e@wv11uWQWaOkhLS6zKBC7TKBnKk1p5KJsWNdSbMusaJz5HjP6mvI69QF3yBMsmW9nANXL2/po3UTr3TPw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
*      # WhateverCode lambda (this is the parameter)
Z[%]   # zipped using infix modulus operator (&infix:«%»)
1 .. * # Range starting from 1 (doesn't stop)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 20 bytes

```arturo
$=>[0map&=>[%&<=1+]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?dZ54Av)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
LR1+z%
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6Fst8ggy1q1QhHKjYgpvu0RY6CoZAbAakDIHYREfBGEiZArEBRNQSiI3AouY6CqZgBBMDY6AO01iIeQA)

##### Explanation

```python
LR1+z%  # D flag duplicates input
LR      # Push range(len(input))
  1+    # Add one
    z%  # Mod the input by this
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 6 bytes

```
g%U,#g
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhbL0lVDdZTTIRyo2E33aAsdBUMgNgNShkBsoqNgDKRMgdgAImoJxEZgUXMdBVMwgomBMVCHKcwOAA)

##### Explanation

```python
g%U,#g  # Input on command line
g%      # The input list mod
   ,#g  # range(len(input))
  U     # incremented
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 22 bytes

```ruby
~:zip&(1..)|:*&(:/&:%)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW2-qsqjIL1DQM9fQ0a6y01DSs9NWsVDUhkjdVChTcoqMNDXQULHUULHQUzHUUzHQUTHUUTHQUjHUUjHQUDGNjIWoXLIDQAA)

### Explanation

```ruby
~:zip & (1..) | :* & (:/ & :%)

~:zip & (1..) |                 # Zip with endless range 1.., then
                :* & (       )  # Map with...
                      :/ & :%   #   Reduce with modulo
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 21 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map((x,y)=>x%~y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NCoMwEITvPsVcChFt7NbGH4o@i8GqWKyKStFLX90msUJdlmWZzTeZp3zLMR/qfjq33aNYy2SVSSr5S/aMze5iJ@l8@iz2ercyugAxEAEhEAACuAE@cAXIUkcyq2@W49GKQJGGiEBGJwHtp5QYtFGhocRP0a1eCm28tb9bbv8EJg0dUG38h1oqlhp7vIwPRd/IvGAed7zKnZI079qxawredBUr2cTHvqkn5sHxbFXrFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 26 bytes

```
f(L)=mod(L,[1...L.length])
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gkuj7knqhb)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ż%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLFvCUiLCIiLCJbOCwgMTgsIDYsIDExLCAxNCwgMywgMTUsIDEwLCA2LCAxOSwgMTIsIDMsIDcsIDUsIDUsIDE5LCAxMiwgMTIsIDE0LCA1XSJd)

```
 % # Modulo by
ż  # Range from 1 to length of input
```

Comment: Polyglots with Thunno 2!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 46 bytes

```py
lambda x:[0]+[x[i]%i for i in range(1,len(x))]
```

Simples ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `range(1,len(x)+1)`? But then you're better off doing `range(len(x))` and doing `lambda x:[x[i]%-~i for i in range(len(x))]`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well you could do that if you want an IndexError...

Comment: Does not raise any error for me.

Comment: Oh, and your solution, including my golf, is also compatible with Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 68 bytes

Go isn't hopelessly defeated (kinda is, but nvm that) because it has that nice `range` which is the equivalent of Python's `enumerate()`.

```go
func f(l[]int)(r[]int){for i,v:=range l{r=append(r,v%(i+1))};return}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7dCoJAEEbvfYohCHZpiMayX3yH7qOLpVxZ0lUG9UZ8dhvXoKsa@Bj44JyZvBpr83iZPIPSOB@5sq64gYUtm8VoW/8Aq4rb3flGK553bysGh905ZeOFK3pOTV1n/qkYu6VyK9J6uHDWtOyHWTK5le4jkBH1@spiKryyKjh72iCcEI4IB4Q9QoKwQ9gixAg0aP0TFIKOASGSzBAJPhmnVqwUh/YQtMm3CxEi@Xfg73X6fDeMbw)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 37 bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET as$v)echo$v%++$k." ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lEu/uGmIbrWRooKSjZAnEFkBsDsRmQGwKxCZAbAzERkBsqBRr/T8tvyg1MTlDA6xTIbFYpUwzNTkjX6VMVVtbJVtPSUHJ@v//r3n5uslAVakA)

Output separeted by an underscore

[PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET as$v)echo$v%++$k,_;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lEu/uGmIbrWRooKSjZAnEFkBsDsRmQGwKxCZAbAzERkBsqBRr/T8tvyg1MTlDA6xTIbFYpUwzNTkjX6VMVVtbJVsn3vr//695@brJQDWpAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,i=1:l and[l[0]%i]+f(l[1:],i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoAwEAXAq7xGUHyF69@AJwkpIhIMrFHExtPHmft7jyu1OYdV/bntHsq4ilH4tFu1jSuiq0OpVoxjrKXK9xPTi1BaaYiFmImJGImB6ImOaAlxVf4B)

A recursive solution. One byte longer than using `enumerate`. Other attempts:

```python
f=lambda l,i=1:l and[l.pop(0)%i]+f(l,i+1)
f=lambda l,i=0:l[i:]and[l[i]%-~i]+f(l,i+1)
f=lambda l:l and f(l[:-1])+[l[-1]%len(l)]
```

The last one really wants to use `pop` but the order of evaluation is wrong.

Comment: Save five bytes by printing with `def f(a,m=1):print a[m-1]%m;f(a,m+1)`, but I see that still does not beat your 35 byte full program solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 18 bytes

```
{map (*+1)R%*,.kv}
```

Accepts the list as its sole argument.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl6, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
say $_%++$ for @*ARGS
```

And a more readable version:

```
# Store initial index state
# The "++$" in the golf version increments an anonymous state variable for this.
my $index = 0;
# Iterate over the command-line arguments
for @*ARGS -> $number {
    # Increment the current index
    $index++;
    # Print out the result for this element
    say $number % $index;
}
```

Usage:

```
perl6 whatever-you-named-it.p6 [space-separated numbers go here]
```

Note that if we don't need to actually *print* the output, we can remove the initial `say`, saving 4 bytes to bring the total down to 17.

Answer (score 0):

## k, 12 bytes

```
{(1+!#x)!'x}
```

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%7B%281%2B%21%23x%29%21%27x%7D%27%2810%20%209%20%208%20%207%20%206%20%205%20%204%20%203%20%202%20%201%3B8%2018%20%206%2011%2014%20%203%2015%2010%20%206%2019%2012%20%203%20%207%20%205%20%205%2019%2012%2012%2014%20%205%3B1%3B1%201%29)

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 12 bytes

```
%pLI
ILOM
ri
```

It's a bit hard to see because there's no line break after the result is printed. Input is taken one number at a time, seperated by linebreaks.

#### Explanation:

Read a line and cast it to an integer:

```
ri
```

Load quick storage (initially an empty string) and increment it (autocasts to int; --> 1)

```
IL
```

Calculate and print modulo, load quick storage again, increment and save it:

```
%pLI
   M
```

Go back to the start:

```
  O
```

#### Example in- and output:

```
10
0
9
1
8
2
7
3
6
1
5
5
4
4
3
3
2
2
1
1
```

For one byte the output can look nicer:

```
%pLI
ILnM
riO
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
;ru@♀%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9@6qNTh0cwG1f//DQ10LHUsdMx1zHRMdUx0jHWMdAwB)

Explanation:

```
;ru@♀%
;ru     push [1, len(L)]
   @♀%  modulo of pairs from each list ([L[0]%1, L[1]%2, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 40 bytes

```
->q{q.each_with_index.map{|n,i|n%(i+1)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 25 bytes

```
#(map mod %(rest(range)))
```

`(range)` generates an infinite sequence of integers starting from 0, `rest` drops the first, and `map`ping with multiple sequences applies the operation to corresponding elements (and stops with the shorter sequence).

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 28 characters

```
to_entries[]|.value%(.key+1)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq 'to_entries[]|.value%(.key+1)' <<< '[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]'
0
1
2
3
1
5
4
3
2
1
```

[Try in jq‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/OKA0wRBZYU)

For +5 characters you can enclose all the code in brackets and ask for compact output to [get JSON output](https://jqplay.org/s/fCC4_yWB49). But that not seems to be required.

Answer (score 0):

## [NewStack](https://github.com/LyamBoylan/NewStack/), 3 bytes

```
ᵢ%ṅ
```

### The breakdown:

```
ᵢ    Append user's input to the stack
 %ṅ  Mod stack by 1-based index of each element
```