# Verb arities in J trains

Tags: code-golf, number

### Background

J has trains similar to [APL's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/150380/78410). Given a sequence of verbs (functions), three rightmost verbs are grouped to form a derived verb (a *fork*) recursively, until one or two verbs remain. If the sequence has odd length, the entire train is a chain of forks. Otherwise, two verbs remain at the end, forming a *hook*.

```
    (F G H J K) x             5-train called monadically
->  (F G (H J K)) x
->  (F x) G ((H x) J (K x))   Function arities: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1

    x (F G H J K) y                 5-train called dyadically
->  x (F G (H J K)) y
->  (x F y) G ((x H y) J (x K y))   Function arities: 2, 2, 2, 2, 2

    (F G H J K L) x                 6-train called monadically
->  (F (G H (J K L))) x
->  x F ((G x) H ((J x) K (L x)))   Function arities: 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1

    x (F G H J K L) y               6-train called dyadically
->  x (F (G H (J K L))) y
->  x F ((G y) H ((J y) K (L y)))   Function arities: 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1
```

You don't need to fully understand J trains to solve this challenge. The pattern is pretty simple:

- If the train length is even, the pattern is `[2, 1, 2, 1, ..., 2, 1]` regardless of the train's arity.
- Otherwise (length is odd), if the train is called monadically, the pattern is `[1, 2, 1, 2, ..., 2, 1]`; if called dyadically, the pattern is all 2's.

### Challenge

Given a train's length and arity (monadic is 1, dyadic is 2), output the arities of each function in the train.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
length, arity -> answer
1,      1     -> [1]
1,      2     -> [2]
2,      1     -> [2, 1]
2,      2     -> [2, 1]
3,      1     -> [1, 2, 1]
3,      2     -> [2, 2, 2]
4,      1     -> [2, 1, 2, 1]
4,      2     -> [2, 1, 2, 1]
9,      1     -> [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
9,      2     -> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
10,     1     -> [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
10,     2     -> [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: May we output a list or string with any two distinct values?

Comment: @chunes No, here 1 and 2 have specific meaning, so you need to specifically output those numbers. Outputting a string like `"2121"` is fine though.

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213877/what-valence-does-this-apl-train-have/

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda l,a:(l*[2,l%a+1])[l:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDRCoIwFIbv9xTnJtxqRVveJNiL2IhFisLUYTPp6W0ZS2wKjcO5@M7/n/8w/TR5XfE@i8@9kuX1JkFRGWG1TjhVK7lhgiQqEn2XFyoFFiHAioIkFOrWaIihlBqnD2lhI7tLUenWYLK7a1UYHMD2BAEhCHRTVAayjxfieHD3jMLw2NCtNmECOci/kAvEPaUlbOT8hx/8zRSmo4nlXQKFsynOGM5muelxKdHvo9i7wS/7IXu6eNXccqfn/@lf)

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

It saves one byte to output as a string.

```python
lambda l,a:(l*`21+l%a`)[l:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBDoIwEEX3PcVsDK1WYisbSfAiSKRGjTUFGigST49FUo0WE5vJLN78/2dSfTeXquT9Odn1ShSHowBFRYzVPOdsoWYiJ6mKs767SHUCFiPAioIgFKrWaEigEBqfbsLCWnR7WerWYBI2WkmDA1huISAEga5laeA8eiFJIAjCayVLPNgbU49xhPSMwvOxZ7f2lGXIQf6CPEPcU1rC3px/8bWfTOFz9GEZKkPR5BZnjCZ3uenm10a/v8XeDX7ZD1nRn1dNhTs9/0//AA)

Answer (score 10):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl) 0.1, 10 bytes

```
<(0.(*(1(+(%.,))2?).
```

[Try it at HBL Online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=PCgwLigqKDEoKyglLiwpKTI/KS4_&a=Nwox)

HBL uses a [half-byte codepage](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md). Each character above represents one hex digit, two characters per byte. Here's a hexdump of the raw binary file:

```
00000000: 3c0a c5c1 c4c8 abdd 29da                 <.......).
```

#### Explanation

If we reverse the desired output, we can see some patterns emerge:

```
3 1  (1 2 1)
3 2  (2 2 2)
4 1  (1 2 1 2)
4 2  (1 2 1 2)
5 1  (1 2 1 2 1)
5 2  (2 2 2 2 2)
```

- The output is some two-element list repeated a number of times and trimmed to a length equal to the first argument.
- The second element of that list is always 2.
- The first element of that list is 2 if the arguments are, respectively, an odd number and 2; otherwise, the first element is 1.

This leads to our initial solution, given here in Thimble, HBL's "ungolfed mode":

```
'(reverse           ; Reverse of
  (take arg1        ; The first (arg1) elements of
   (repeat          ; Repeat the following list...
    (cons           ;  Construct a list from the values...
     (cond          ;   If...
      (mul          ;    Multiply
       (odd? arg1)  ;    parity of arg1
       (dec arg2))  ;    by (arg2 - 1)
      2             ;   ... is nonzero, then 2
      1)            ;   else 1
     2              ;  ... and 2
     nil)           ;  prepended to the empty list
    arg1)))         ; ... (arg1) times
```

Translating this solution into HBL gives `<(0.(*(1(?(*(%.)(-,))21)2?).` (14 bytes). To get to our 10-byte solution, observe that there's a nice relationship between our two arguments and the number we want in our list:

```
 arg1 % 2 | arg2 | num | arg1 % arg2
----------|------|-----|-------------
 0        | 1    | 1   | 0
 0        | 2    | 1   | 0
 1        | 1    | 1   | 0
 1        | 2    | 2   | 1
```

So instead of the conditional, all we need is `(inc (mod arg1 arg2))`.

```
'(reverse
  (take arg1
   (repeat
    (cons
     (inc
      (mod arg1 arg2))
     2
     nil)
    arg1)))
```

Replacing the builtins with their HBL equivalents and removing the opening and closing parentheses (implicit in HBL), this solution maps directly onto the HBL solution given above.

Comment: Nice observation and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
%‘;2ṁḷU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/1UcMMa6OHOxsf7tge@t/y8HLD/wA)

Thanks to Unrelated String for making this work! Port of dingledooper's answer.

```
%‘ṭ2ṁḷU # Dyadic link taking two arguments
    ṁ   # Mold... 
  ;2    # 2 appended to...
%       # The modulo of the two inputs
 ‘      # Plus 1
    ṁ   # To length...
     ḷ  # Left argument (length input)
      U # Reversed
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
%21+sиJs.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f1chQu/jCDq9iPZX//w25LAE)

Comment: Fails for (1,9) and all odd-length inputs in general.

Comment: @Bubbler fixed though it ended up becoming dingledooper port

Comment: `иJ` is the builtin `×`. And here an alternative 9-byter: [`%T*12+²∍R`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fNUTL0Ej70KZHHb1B//8bchkaAAA)

Comment: My alternative 9-byter can actually be a 7-byter like this: [`%>2«²∍R`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f1c7o0OpDmx519Ab9/2/IZWgAAA) (port of [the Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237070/52210))

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.repeating`, 50 bytes

```
[ dupd mod 1 + '[ 2 _ ] over 2 * cycle swap tail ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc89C8JADAbgvb/i3QSFYj@WKriKi4s4lSLHNdXSr/PuqpTS314PhZpkeXkSCCmEtJ2er5fT@bhDRbqlGoaePbWSjK9JkbBle4fSZO2gdNlaCGM6adAI@0Chh/8@9p43enA1InA9LTlccsg8ZB4xj5jHzGPmCfOEebDlh7ffyTSnyHuVo@lyN91glTq/IUP3Iu3iGnKQNcG8hYIVZY1sLn5/HhpHxgpZ@fMH)

This is a port of @dingledooper's excellent [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237060/97916).

There is a locals version that is the same length:

```
[| l a | 2 l a mod 1 + 2array l 2 * cycle l tail ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc@xCsIwEAbgvU/xzwpSYxcVXMXFRZzE4YhXLU3bmMSh1D57jAp6uSH/fUkIV5IOnYvHw26/XaFm17KB5/uDW81@5tgyhaq9wjoOobeuagPI@057kHPUezQUbjCdJuP/L7HOsiFDWgPmqcZfVr@shCvhC@EL4YXwQvhS@FL4PJcf55@TMZ6eMCA8U/vem@6Sbk2hPtMkUphA99pwyoEqg3MsvxNvGrLwgXQ9iy8)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes the length and the arity (in that order) from the data stack as input and leaves a sequence on the data stack as output. Assuming `9 1` is on the data stack when this quotation is called...

| Snippet | Comment | Data stack (the bottom is the top) |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | ``` 9 <--- NOS (next on stack) 1 <--- TOS (top of stack) ``` |
| ``` dupd ``` | Duplicate NOS | ``` 9 9 1 ``` |
| ``` mod ``` | NOS % TOS | ``` 9 0 ``` |
| ``` 1 ``` | Push 1 | ``` 9 0 1 ``` |
| ``` + ``` | NOS + TOS | ``` 9 1 ``` |
| ``` '[ 2 _ ] ``` | Slot TOS into the _ | ``` 9 [ 2 1 ] ``` |
| ``` over ``` | Copy NOS to TOS | ``` 9 [ 2 1 ] 9 ``` |
| ``` 2 ``` | Push 2 | ``` 9 [ 2 1 ] 9 2 ``` |
| ``` * ``` | NOS * TOS | ``` 9 [ 2 1 ] 18 ``` |
| ``` cycle ``` | Repeat NOS until length of TOS | ``` 9 [ 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ] ``` |
| ``` swap ``` | Swap NOS and TOS | ``` [ 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ] 9 ``` |
| ``` tail ``` | Take NOS from index at TOS | ``` [ 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ] ``` |

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 32 bytes

```
\d+
$*
r`11
21
T`1`2`21,1.*
.+,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcohDoAwEERRP@dA0abpbGt6DyRiSUBgEA33XwYxeSP@vN77OSL2M2FZMZ2EEZvTzY2ZZUVJGRH6MI3ZpMkmm@yyyyGHZP3D@gE) Link includes test cases. Takes input in the order arity, length. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the length to unary, conveniently using `1`s.

```
r`11
21
```

Working right-to-left, change every other `1` to a `2`.

```
T`1`2`21,1.*
```

If the arity is two and the length is odd, change all the `1`s to `2`s.

```
.+,
```

Delete the arity.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
%21+S⁰*∷
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2521%2BS%E2%81%B0*%E2%88%B7&inputs=2%0A3&header=&footer=)

*-1 thanks to emanresuA*

Haha 05ab1e porting goes brrrr. When v2.6.0pre2 drops later this week, this'll be 7 bytes:

```
%21+⁰ẋ∷
```

### Explained (old)

```
%21+S⁰*⁰ȯ # Full program, takes arity, length
%         # Push length mod arity,
 21+      # add 21 to that,
    S     # and cast to string. (This value will be called x)
     ⁰    # Push the length,
      *   # and repeat x that many times. (This value will be called y)
       ⁰  # Push the length again,
        ȯ # and push y[length:]
```

Comment: you ported me, and I ported dingledooper lol

Comment: [-1](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2521%2BS%E2%81%B0*%E2%88%B7&inputs=2%0A3&header=&footer=) with the first half

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->l,a{([2,l%a+1]*l)[l,l]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cuRyexWiPaSCdHNVHbMFYrRzM6RycntvZ/tKGOkY6xjomOpY6hQaxebmJBdU1FDVeBQlp0hY5hLJRhFMtV@99QRwEMDMGkrp1CNFAeJmgEFwSqNcJQCRQxRIgboYkbY5qso4AqhaIFhGK5TLDaAtNogtUumKwlLhsxSYRiDDdgImCAGOjgdBU2w2HqjYhTDwA)

Another port of @dingledooper's Python answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 47 bytes

```
(".@,'~'''''}.~2&|)~'(',')',~,&'1&, :(,2&,)'&''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBCsIwEEX3PcWni0wC05CMbhoQBMGVK68gFnHjBTRXT22RNG1FDJMs3rz5A7mn2lKHXQCB4RDet7E4nE/HpGu7Z4o0nJeNop4mkiYmQxxZkVeMoFkUG1JEyVTXy@0BzcEbNAEeHXxmMjIpmDAmUZZQCugZM3kzyUNlv@DLke33lhStD1@/OaSd711XzmxX637EevevPX6fQ5V6)

I would call this one a conscious un-golf, because ofc I could port dingledooper's Python answer to J for fewer bytes...

But it just didn't feel right for a J answer not to use J's train parsing code to compute the answer.

### the idea

First, we construct a verb `1&, :(,2&,)` that prepends 1 to its argument (say `a b c`) when called with 1 argument:

```
1 a b c
```

but plops 2 in the middle when called with 2 args:

```
a b c 2 a b c
```

Next we duplicate that verb `length` times to form a train, and then invoke the train on the empty list `''`.  More precisely, we call:

```
train ''
```

if our arity is 1, and:

```
'' train ''
```

if our arity is 2.

With that setup, J's train execution will do the required computation for us.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ḶU|%Ḃ‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2hNaoPdzQ9apjx3/3h7i3Wj5rWPGqYY6Wg8KhhrrXS4eX6QAGQxLGuyP//o6MNdQxjdYCkEZA0ArONwGxjMNsYzDYBs03AbEsw2xLMNjSAaDYA8mIB)

Like Dingledooper's answer, but a bit different.

```
ḶU       range [L-1..0]
  |%     bitwise OR by L%A
            (if L%A=0, this does nothing;
             if L%A=1, it makes the whole range odd)
    Ḃ‘   mod 2, add 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 31 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(l,a)tail(rep(2:(l%%a+1),l),l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRydRsyQxM0ejKLVAw8hKI0dVNVHbUFMnB4T@p2kY6iiAgaGmMpjWtVOINozlQkgYIUkYgSSMsOgAihkiyxlhkTPGZpOOAro0mlYQAkmb4LAVYYAJDrsRKixxuwCTRNaAxU2YCBxoBjp4XIndEpgeI2L1/AcA)

Based od [@dingledooper's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237060/55372).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 46 bytes (44 using puts)

```c
i;f(l,a){for(i=l;i--;)printf(L"122"+i%2+l%a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBCoMwEEX3OcUgKAkqmKkbiXqC3qC4EKklkKpYXYlnt1FqrY2FhmEWb/78P6Twb0UxTVKUVHk5G8q6pTJRQvq@YE0rq66kZ4sjWq600VV2zsQ4aQz3XFZA2UCWFQ1UwoWKEx4I11Wag9SeaQiOAyqOGBR11cmqv4IgMKdxJpq@e1DLYi@Cn2Qk48Q9WB5fup/ChWdkhfiGmBE0lJrwjeMXP5nOHuxHu5W5MhIepqyL4WHWOo1@JZp9Exs3mKU/JPB@XnVkvurxP/0T)

- Based on @dingledooper [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237060/84844)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
\%J+░*h½≥
```

Port of [*@dingledooper*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237060/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z9G1Uv70bSJWhmH9j7qXPr/v6GCIZehghGXEZA2AtLGQNoYSJsAaRMgbQmkLYG0oQFIoYGCEQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
\          # Swap the two (implicit) input-integers
 %         # Modulo
  J+       # Add 21
    ░      # Convert it to a string
     *     # Repeat it the first (implicit) input-integer amount of times
      h    # Push the length of this string (without popping)
       ½   # Halve it
        ≥  # Remove that many leading digits from the string
           # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｎθ↓Ｉ……⊕﹪θＮ³θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDyiW/PE9HwTmxuETDuTI5J9U5I79AIygxLz1VwzMvuSg1NzWvJDVFwzc/pTQnX6NQRwHZHE1NTR0FYyAuBLKs//@3VDD6r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ              Input the length as an integer
     …          Range from
        θ       Input length
       ﹪        Reduced modulo
         Ｎ      Arity as an integer
      ⊕         Incremented
          ³     Until 3 (exclusive)
    …           Cycled to length
           θ    Input length
   Ｉ            Cast to string
  ↓             Output right-to-left
```

Instead of `↓`, either `←` or `⮌` can be used for vertical output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 61 bytes

```rust
|l,a|->Vec<_>{(0..l).rev().map(move|x|(x|l%a)%2+1).collect()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCsIwFET3PcW3UMjHNBjdWa23cCuhpFD4TUuMpZDk7LFqFWcxi3nMMPZxd6k10KvOMASfwSLSDtpzCsRVKOurbk632rOdEITC6omh6NXI@mHSYQ5sDlQoLPZbiaIZiHTjGMZUvafawQJBZ0AKIeW6/wVqBYe//KXRdsaR2bDcRw4@QlmDP15izpdHvGWLI1a/Ssw@HtMT)

Port of @Lynn's Jelly answer.

Generates range `l-1 .. 0`, bitwise ORs each item with `l modulo a`, then modulos the result with `2` and adds `1`

`Range` in rust (`(start..stop)`) must be ascending, as it returns an empty iterator if `start >= stop`, so we have to `.rev()` the range to reverse it before mapping. Thankfully though the `stop` of a range is exclusive, so `(0..l)` generates range `0` to `l-1` inclusive.